# Fast replace the same text in few files in Liquid XML Studio

Tags: liquid-xml

I need to find and replace text within a number of large XML files, is there a way to automate this process using Liquid XML?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before posting a question please read: **[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Answer (score 0):

Open the files that you want to replace, then use the [find and replace dialog](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Reference/XmlStudio/webframe.html?Find_and_Replace.html) (Ctrl_Shift+F).  You can set the FnR to work on `all files` in the project or `All Open Documents` or even just the `current document`.

Answer (score 0):

I know find and replace dialog, but i think about something to make this process maximum automatic, quick and simple. I have a lot of documents when i must replace one phrase. Maybe some script or something?